# ListView and remembering data

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewbinder

I have some problems with a `ListView`(it's more of a visual problem), it remembers data such as text values from `TextViews`, from the `ListView`'s rows, but tangles or forgets aspects regarding the `TextViews` background color.
The problem shows up only when the `ListView` contains many rows. I work with a `SimpleCursorAdapter` and a `ViewBinder` and want to highlight a `TextView` if a condition occurs:

In the `ViewBinder` implementation:

```
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
    CharSequence display;
    if(view.getId() == R.id.dueDate){
        long timestamp = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(3));
        display=DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(timestamp); 

        if(timestamp+DaysToMillis(5)> new Date().getTime())
        ((TextView) view).setBackgroundResource(R.color.marker_red);

        ((TextView) view).setText(display);
        return true; 
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

So again: when there are many rows the `ListView` seems to tangle the background color. Some times when I re-scroll, it change's again the `TextView`'s background and I can't seem to find the bug or the `ListView`'s logic.

So, does the `setViewValue(..)` method gets called every time before inflating a row? Even if you scroll up or down and a row that's not visible anymore get's visible again? Or the `setViewValue(..)` method gets called just for a initial row inflating process and then the created objects are keept in the `ListView`'s memory?

P.S. The text values from the same `TextView` is displayed correctly. I used the same logic in the same `setViewValue(..)` method.

Answer (score 0):

*Same newbie*

It seems to me (and if I'm wrong please correct me... especially if you are Roman Guy) that ViewBinder, with it's setViewValue method recycles the listView's rows...

- setViewValue(..) gets called for every "FROM - TO" binding for every row displayed, even for rows that were already inflated, and by scrolling up/down they got displayed again;
- and regarding my amassing piece of code, for a row that gets displayed again:
  `((TextView) view).setText(display);` - will set the correct content, same timestamp will get processed... but if it doesn't passes the:

  `if(timestamp+DaysToMillis(5)> new Date().getTime())
                  ((TextView) view).setBackgroundResource(R.color.marker_red);`
  -the current TextView might have for background the background from a recycled TextView
- anyways I had to add an `else ((TextView) view).setBackgroundResource(0);` to my `if`